# Define worker role's app.config section handler in webrole's model folder

Tags: c#, app-config, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

this is my first time creating a custom configuration section class for app.config for the worker role. I was able to do so successfully for the worker role when I defined my custom section class inside the WorkerRole1 project, and originally the app.config section as so:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="environmentInfoGroup">
    <section name="environmentInfo" type="WorkerRole1.EnvironmentInfoSection, WorkerRole1" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

However, now I moved the EnvironmentInfoSection class to the MvcWebRole1.Models and changed the app.config to:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="environmentInfoGroup">
    <section name="environmentInfo" type="MvcWebRole1.Models.EnvironmentInfoSection, MvcWebRole1.Models" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

At the line of

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("environmentInfoGroup/environmentInfo") as EnvironmentInfoSection;
```

I got an exception of

```
InnerException  {"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for environmentInfoGroup/environmentInfo: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcWebRole1.Models' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Since currently my worker role is using other classes from the same folder in the webRole, does that mean I cannot share classes across from webRole to workerRole for configuration things? Or is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that doesn't directly apply as an answer to the problem. 
However, what I did was having two same EnvironmentInfoSection defined in both worker and web role projects and two same config sections in app.config and Web.config.

I noticed that in app.config:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="environmentInfoGroup">
    <section name="environmentInfo" type="WorkerRole1.EnvironmentInfoSection, WorkerRole1" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

is correct, but in Web.config (WebRole)

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="environmentInfoGroup">
    <section name="environmentInfo" type="WebRole1.Models.EnvironmentInfoSection" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

is the correct way. Note the difference is that in Web.config, there is no "comma" followed by the namespace after in the type definition.